# How to resolve ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH error when wnabling SSL in Java Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to generate a keystore and enable SSL in my Spring Boot application, but I'm getting the error **ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH**.

**Here's what I've done:**

1. Exported my valid .crt certificate generated by Let's Encrypt.
2. Imported my .crt into a .p12 keystore with this command:

> keytool -import -alias springboot -file myCertificate.crt -keystore
> springboot.p12 -storepass password

3. Added the keystore "springboot.p12" to 'src/main/resources' of the project.
4. Added the configuration in the application.yml file:

> ```
>     ssl:
>         key-store: classpath:springboot.p12
>         key-store-password: password
> ```

5. Started the server at https://localhost:8080/ and received the "ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH" message in Chrome.

I believe I might be doing something wrong in keystore generation. **Does anyone have any tips?**

**Note:** I tested this update in production, and instead of ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH, I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT."

**Note2:** If I generete a self-sign certificate that error not occurrus, but I need a valid certificate

Comment: Let's encrypted doesn't issue certificates for localhost. Certificates only work correctly if you install them on the server they are issued for and then you have to use the full address which is noted in the certificate for accessing it.

Comment: @Robert my application is running on a subdomain and the certificate was generated for the domain. For example: domain.com is where I got the certificate from and app.domain.com is where my application is. In this case, do I need to generate another certificate for the subdomain?

Comment: You need to obtain and use a cert that _contains_ the name you use to connect, OR (optionally) a wildcard form of that name -- you can get a wildcard for \*.example.com and use it for fred.example.com and wilma.example.com but NOT example.com or boo.boo.example.com (two levels of name). LetsEncrypt will issue a cert for more than one name (up to 100 IIRC) so you can get e.g. example.com,sub.example.com or example.com,\*.example.com . But name mismatch can't cause the error you're reporting -- a more likely cause for that is if your keystore contains only the cert and not the privatekey; ...

Comment: ... you cannot convert the _two or more_ PEM files created by certbot (if that's what you used) to a keystore with `keytool`, you need instead `openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey privatekey.pem -out p12keystore` (see about a hundred existing Qs) or something like keystore-explorer.org .